# Can't connect to running container with Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am able to successfully run my container using following command:

**docker run -d -p 8080:80 sampleimage**

Also, running **docker ps** results in following output:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

maybe 8080 port is blocked by firewall
try to disable your windows firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).